# when sticky positioned div is higher than screen, it starts scrolling the page behind before scroll the sticky div content

Tags: css, position, sticky

I've set position: sticky in my header div to keep it on the top while scrolling. Adding also a top: 0px. And it works perfect.

But this header has a drop down menu which opens more submenu options using posotion: absolute, and its content is higher than the screen height (lot of options... long list). In that case, when I try to scroll down to see more options, what is scrolling is the page behind. And when it reaches the end of the page, then it starts scrolling the menu options.

What I would like is, when the drop down menu is open, scrollt it, and not the page behind.

How could i change this behavior?

Small code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #header {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0px;
            background-color: #ffd800;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="Menu">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
        (some content)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Menu div there is an option which opens a long list of more options, taking more space than the available in the screen (imagine it in a mobile device). Then I start to scroll down to reach these hidden options at the bottom of the screen, but the screen seems static, because what is scrolling is the Page div behind the menu. When the end of Page div is reached, then starts scrolling down the menu.

What i need is to scroll the menu options when the submenu is open.

Comment: could you post something in snippet? From what I'm reading, I've different ways to understand...

Comment: for the moment i could get it work by setting to the opening submenu div `height: 50vh` and `overflow-y: scroll;` Not too much elegant but i can scroll the menu content first now.

Comment: great, as far it's working!